# How to resolve the findbug Sequence of calls to java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap may not be atomic

Tags: java, findbugs, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

Hi I am getting the bug "Sequence of calls to java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap may not be atomic " when i am running find bug in my project for the below code.

```
public static final ConcurrentHashMap<String,Vector<Person>> personTypeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Vector<Person>>();

    private static void setDefaultPersonGroup() {


        PersonDao crud = PersonDao.getInstance();
        List<Person> personDBList = crud.retrieveAll();
        for (Person person : personDBList) {
            Vector<Person> personTypeCollection = personTypeMap.get(person
                    .getGroupId());
            if (personTypeCollection == null) {
                personTypeCollection = new Vector<Person>();
                personTypeMap.put(personTypeCollection.getGroupId(),
                        personTypeCollection);
            }
            personTypeCollection.add(person);
        }
    }
```

I am facing the problem at the line
personTypeMap.put(personTypeCollection.getGroupId(),
                        personTypeCollection);

Can any one help me to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Compound operations are unsafe in concurrent environment.

What compound operations are you performing?

- 1) You are checking whether `Map` contains a vector for a key
- 2) You are putting a new `Vector` if no value is found

So this is a two step action and is compound, so it is unsafe.

Why are they not safe?

Because they are ***not atomic***. Think of a scenario in which you have two threads.

Consider this timeline:

```
Thread 1 --- checks for == null -> true                                           puts a new Vector

Thread 2 ---                      checks for ==null -> true    puts a new Vector
```

Use `putIfAbsent()` method on `ConcurrentHashMap`, which provides you an atomic solution to what you are trying to perform.

[ConcurrentHashMap#putIfAbsent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29)

References:

- [Proper use of putIfAbsent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743622/concurrenthashmap-avoid-extra-object-creation-with-putifabsent)

Comment: Hi when i am using putifabsent then find bug throw the error like "Return value of putIfAbsent is ignored, but personTypeCollection is reused in setDefaultPersonGroup()

Comment: putIfAbsent returns a value, which can be null if the key was not mapped to anything or previous value for that key. So you should use the return value.

Comment: Welcome. You may also see answer of @Bohemian in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743622/concurrenthashmap-avoid-extra-object-creation-with-putifabsent

Answer (score 3):

[That findbugs message](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#AT_OPERATION_SEQUENCE_ON_CONCURRENT_ABSTRACTION) is telling you in the case of multi-threaded access it's not safe:

You're fetching something from `personTypeMap`, checking to see if it's `null`, then putting a new entry in if that's the case. Two threads could easily interleave here:

> Thread1: get from map
>   Thread2: get from map
>   Thread1: check returned value for null
>   Thread1: put new value
>   Thread2: check returned value for null
>   Thread2: put new value

(Just as an example; in reality the ordering is not a given - the point is both threads get `null` then act on it)

You should be creating a new entry, then calling `personTypeMap.putIfAbsent()` as this guarantees atomicity.

Comment: Hi when i am using putifabsent() then find bug throw the error like "Return value of putIfAbsent is ignored, but personTypeCollection is reused in setDefaultPersonGroup()

Answer (score 0):

In your case, your code should looks like this:

```
public static final ConcurrentHashMap<String,Vector<Person>> personTypeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Vector<Person>>();

private static void setDefaultPersonGroup() {
    PersonDao crud = PersonDao.getInstance();
    List<Person> personDBList = crud.retrieveAll();
    for (Person person : personDBList) {
        // the putIfAbsent works in the same way of your
        //previous code, but in atomic way
        Vector<Person> personTypeCollection = personTypeMap.putIfAbsent(person
                .getGroupId());
        personTypeCollection.add(person);
    }
}
```