# What is the difference between putIfAbsent and computeIfAbsent in Java 8 Map ?

Tags: java, java-8

Reading an interesting articles the guys claims that the difference between the two function are:

> Both functions aspire to add an element if the specified Key is not
>   already present in Map.
>
> putIfAbsent adds an element with the specified Value whereas
>   computeIfAbsent adds an element with the value computed using the Key. 
>   http://www.buggybread.com/2014/10/java-8-difference-between-map.html

And

> We’ve seen that putIfAbsent removes the imperative way of having to
>   define the if-statement, but what if fetching the Java articles is
>   really hurting our performance?
>
> To optimise this, we don’t want to fetch the articles until we’re
>   really sure we need them — meaning we need to know if the key is
>   absent before fetching the articles.
>   http://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-02-14-java-8-declarative-ways-of-modifying-a-map-using-compute-merge-and-replace/

I didn't ready understand what are the differences can you please elaborate more on these two functions ?

Comment: To have or to have not. If you have the value you can put it; if you don't have it you have to compute and then put it.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743622/concurrenthashmap-avoid-extra-object-creation-with-putifabsent, looks like a duplicate also

Answer (score 260, accepted):

**Difference #1**

[`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) takes a mapping function, that is called to obtain the value if the key is missing.

[`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) takes the value directly.

If the value is expensive to obtain, then `putIfAbsent` wastes that if the key already exists.

A common "expensive" value is e.g. `new ArrayList<>()` for when you're creating a `Map<K, List<V>>`, where creating a new list when the key already exists (which then discards the new list) generates unnecessary garbage.

---

**Difference #2**

[`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) returns "the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key, or null if the computed value is null".

[`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) returns "the previous value associated with the specified key, or null if there was no mapping for the key".

So, if the key already exists, they return the same thing, but if the key is missing, `computeIfAbsent` returns the computed value, while `putIfAbsent` return null.

---

**Difference #3**

Both method define "absent" as key missing or existing value is null, but:

[`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) will not put a null value if the key is absent.

[`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) will put the value if the key is absent, even if the value is null.

It makes no difference for future calls to [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), [`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-), and [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) calls, but it does make a difference to calls like [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) and [`containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: #2 difference caused some NPEs because I was trying `return map.putIfAbsent("key", someMethodReturningNotNullObj);` inside a `fn` function and I was wondering why the hell I was getting nulls from my `fn` function. `computeIfAbsent` is the way!

Comment: Returning the old value makes putIfAbsent() consistent with put(), which also returns the old value.

Comment: @reggoodwin `putIfAbsent` is not consistent with `put`, since `putIfAbsent` leaves an existing value unchanged, while `put` replaces the value, hence the "if absent" part of the method name.

Comment: Hello, I guess what I meant was that both methods never return the new value passed into them. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 128):

Suppose you have a `Map<String,ValueClass>`.

```
map.putIfAbsent("key", new ValueClass());
```

will create a `ValueClass` instance anyway, even if the "key" key is already in the `Map`. This would just create an unnecessary instance.

On the other hand

```
map.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new ValueClass());
```

will only create a `ValueClass` instance if the "key" key is not already in the `Map` (or is mapped to a `null` value).

Therefore `computeIfAbsent` is more efficient.

`putIfAbsent` is equivalent to:

```
ValueClass value = new ValueClass();
if (map.get("key") == null) {
    map.put("key",value);
}
```

while `computeIfAbsent` is equivalent to:

```
if (map.get("key") == null) {
    map.put("key",new ValueClass());
}
```

Another small difference between the two methods is that `computeIfAbsent` will not put a `null` value for an absent key. `putIfAbsent` will.

Comment: One fairly frequent use for computeIfAbsent would be a `Map<X,List<Y>>` where you have to create a List on first encounter of a key value. Originally one did a get, test, new, put... Now it's just the `computeIfAbsent(..., new ArrayList())`

Answer (score 18):

You can understand the difference by carefully looking at the method signatures:

- `putIfAbsent` takes a key and value, and puts the value in the map if there is no value for that key in the map.
- `computeIfAbsent` takes a key and a `Function`. If there is no value for that key in the map, the function is called to create the value, which is then put in the map.

If you already have the value, use `putIfAbsent`.

If you don't have the value yet and creating the value is an expensive operation (for example, the value has to be looked up in a database), then use `computeIfAbsent`, so that the expensive operation doesn't need to be performed in case the map already contains a value for the specified key.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe the default implementations can clarify a little bit more....

`default V putIfAbsent​(K key, V value)`
The default implementation is equivalent to, for this map:

```
 V v = map.get(key);
  if (v == null)
      v = map.put(key, value);
  return v;
```

On the other hand:

```
default V computeIfAbsent​(K key,
                          Function<? super K,? extends V> mappingFunction)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (map.get(key) == null) {
     V newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key);
     if (newValue != null)
         map.put(key, newValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`V putIfAbsent(K key, V value)` - If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null.

`V computeIfAbsent(K key, Function<? super K,? extends V> mappingFunction)` - If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null.

Reading documentation can give you more obvious answer.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been answered. I took a little time to understand ("expensive operation doesn't need to be performed in case the map already contains a value for the specified key in computeIfAbsent")
I am putting my understanding here. Hope this will be helpful to others:

`putIfAbsent()` behaves simply as `put()` when map already contains the value for the specified key. `putIfAbsent()` only checks whether key is null or not.
If it is not null then it returns the value and then map fetch that value again.

However, in `computeIfAbsent()` there is null check for both key and value. During null check for value, if it is not null then existing value from the map object
is assigned to newValue and it is returned. That's why there is no need to again fetch the value as existing value from map is re-used.

Refer to following program for reference:

```
public class MapTest1 {
    public static final String AJAY_DEVGAN = "Ajay Devgn";
    public static final String AUTOBIOGRAPHY = "Autobiography";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapTest1 mt = new MapTest1();
        mt.testPutCompute();
    }

    private void testPutCompute() {
        Map<String, List<String>> movies = getMovieObject();
        System.out.println("\nCalling putIfAbsent method.....");
        //System.out.println(movies.get(AJAY_DEVGAN));
        //movies.put(AJAY_DEVGAN, getAjayDevgnMovies());
        movies.putIfAbsent(AJAY_DEVGAN, getAjayDevgnMovies());
        
        System.out.println("\nCalling computeIfAbsent method......");
        //System.out.println(movies.get(AUTOBIOGRAPHY));
        movies.computeIfAbsent(AUTOBIOGRAPHY, t -> getAutobiographyMovies());
        
    }

    private Map<String, List<String>> getMovieObject() {
        Map<String, List<String>> movies = new HashMap<>();     

        movies.put(AJAY_DEVGAN, getAjayDevgnMovies());
        movies.put(AUTOBIOGRAPHY, getAutobiographyMovies());
        
        System.out.println(movies);
        return movies;
    }

    private List<String> getAutobiographyMovies() {
        System.out.println("Getting autobiography movies");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("M.S. Dhoni - The Untold Story");
        list.add("Sachin: A Billion Dreams");
        return list;
    }

    private List<String> getAjayDevgnMovies() {
        System.out.println("Getting Ajay Devgn Movies");
        List<String> ajayDevgnMovies = new ArrayList<>();
        ajayDevgnMovies.add("Jigar");
        ajayDevgnMovies.add("Pyar To Hona Hi Tha");
        return ajayDevgnMovies;
    }
}
```

Refer to following code for `putIfAbsent()` and `computeIfAbsent()` from interface `Map.class`

```
public interface Map<K,V> {
.....

 default V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
        V v = get(key);
        if (v == null) {
            v = put(key, value);
        }

        return v;
    }
    
 default V computeIfAbsent(K key,
            Function<? super K, ? extends V> mappingFunction) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(mappingFunction);
        V v;
        if ((v = get(key)) == null) {
            V newValue;
            if ((newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key)) != null) {
                put(key, newValue);
                return newValue;
            }
        }

        return v;
    }   
.........
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Take this simple Example for `putIfAbsent()`:

```
Map myMap = new HashMap();
myMap.put(1,"ABC");
myMap.put(2,"XYZ");
myMap.put(3,"GHI");
//Output of map till this point is : 1-> "ABC", 2-> "XYZ", 3-> "GHI"
myMap.putIfAbsent(3,"cx");
//Output of map till this point is : 1-> "ABC", 2-> "XYZ", 3-> "GHI"
```

`cx` will be value of `3` if there is no Value of `3` in the map already.

Comment: the question was about the difference between `putIfAbsent()` and `computeIfAbsent`, not just about what `putIfAbsent()` does.

Comment: I think you mix up `key` and `value` here. See [`Class HashMap<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).