# How to add new member in ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>> without synchronized or lock

Tags: java

I've read question [ConcurrentHashMap: avoid extra object creation with “putIfAbsent”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743622/concurrenthashmap-avoid-extra-object-creation-with-putifabsent). For `ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>`, multiple threads will get-set the same list. Before `values.add(value);` get executed, entry may be removed and new member fail to be added. How to add new member in `ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>` without `synchronized` or `lock`?

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>> entries =
                        new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>();

public void record(String key, String value) {
    List<String> values = entries.get(key);
    if (values == null) {
        values = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
        List<String> values2 = entries.putIfAbsent(key, values);
        if (values2 != null)
            values = values2;  
    }
    values.add(value); // entry may be removed here, and this member will lose.
}
```

Comment: use `computeIfAbsent` and `computeIfPresent`

Comment: @Antoniossss or even just plain `compute`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `computeXXX` methods are thread-safe (and atomic!), and prevent each other from messing things up. It's not completely lock-free, but it's a lot better than synchronizing by hand.

```
public void record(String key, String value) {
    entries.compute(key, (k, v) -> {
        List<String> vals = v;
        if(vals == null)
            vals = new ArrayList<>();
        vals.add(value);
        return vals;
    });
}
```

I made the list a regular `ArrayList`, since in the above code the `compute` should guarantee visibility. If other code is dependent on them being `synchronizedLists`, change accordingly (or rewrite the other code).

Example delete method:

```
public void delete(String key, String value) {
    entries.compute(key, (k, v) -> {
        List<String> vals = v;
        if(vals == null)
            return null; // No mapping, return null to keep the status quo

        vals.remove(value); // Or whatever you intend to do
        return vals.isEmpty() ? null : vals;
    });
}
```

Comment: If Java 8+. Otherwise, a lock-free solution seems impossible, since `record` must be atomic.

Comment: @kagmole I don't provide solutions for obsolete Java versions.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm new to symbol `->` and have read docs about `compute()`. Can you show me the key code how  to delete element in the list and delete the whole list if it's empty?

Comment: @Hel if you return `null` from `compute` it will remove the mapping. You can make a similar delete method that uses `compute`, removes an element from the list and then returns null if the list is empty, or the list itself if it still has elements in it.

Comment: @Kayaman Code can't be compiled. `compute()` should take 2 parameters. Am I missing sth?

Comment: @Hel my bad, it's missing the key parameter. There, fixed.

Comment: @Kayaman if I recall correctly synchronized would be used only when there is contention on non-empty bin