# How to achieve Map putIfAbsent semantics with computeIfAbsent efficiency?

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Value> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

boolean foo(String key) {
    Value value = map.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        value = map.putIfAbsent(key, new Value());
        if (value == null) {
            // do some stuff
            return true;
        }
    }
    // do some other stuff
    return false;
 }
```

Assume that `foo()` is called by multiple threads concurrently. Also assume that calling `new Value()` is expensive. The code is verbose and can still result in redundant `Value` objects created. Can the above logic be implemented in a way that guarantees no redundant `Value` objects are created (i.e. `new Value()` is called at most once)? I'm looking for a clean implementation- minimal code without acquiring locks explicitly.

`computeIfAbsent` could have been a good alternative, however its return semantics are not in line with the required logic.

Comment: Not sure I understand why you think `Value value = map.computeIfAbsent(key, Value::new);` is not applicable.

Comment: @assylias Well, Value constructor does not take a key. But there is nothing wrong with a lambda that ignores the param. `computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new Value())`

Comment: @assylias I'm referring to the return semantics of `computeIfAbsent` versus `putIfAbsent`. The logic in the question takes separate code paths depending on whether an entry is created or not. We can't cleanly figure that out using `computeIfAbsent`

Comment: Sounds like you have a race condition. Two threads call this method, #1 creates and adds a new object, the #2 gets the new object. If #2 starts first, it will act as though #1 has already completed. Based on your reply to my other comment, maybe you should consider using 'compute' in which case you get the old value and you can have the special branching.

Comment: @matt not sure I understand how a race condition is possible; `compute` also does not expose whether an entry was created or not, therefore code outside of `compute` that requires such an input (such as the conditional `return` statements)  would not work.

Comment: @matt `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent` is atomic, no race condition is possible

Answer (score 3):

Some minimal code that does the job:

```
boolean foo(String key) {
    AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean();
    Value value = map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> {flag.set(true); return new Value();});
    if (flag.get()) {
        // do some stuff
    } else {
        // do some other stuff
    }
    return flag.get();
}
```

Comment: Right, but still, JDK providing a `putIfAbsent` that gets a lambda for supplying the value would have been a lot cleaner :)

Comment: @DanielNitzan Yes and no. Smaller interfaces are easier to use. An interface with 200 methods might be comprehensive, but that doesn't mean it's easy to use if you have to spend ages looking for the exact method which meets your needs. Just because you personally have an edge case where it's inconvenient doesn't mean the authors didn't make the right decision.

Comment: @Michael I do not disagree with your reasoning in general. However, I feel that in this specific case, the authors should have augmented `putIfAbsent` (as a useful API method in itself) by providing a lambda version of it.

Comment: @Michael Also, I wouldn't call it an edge case, `putIfAbsent` exists for a good reason, after all. Taking different action based on whether an entry was created or not, is not something unheard of.

Comment: @DanielNitzan Well, there is no point arguing about it. It does not exist, and probably never will. So you're welcome to think the designers made a huge mistake if you want, I was just trying to provide some rationale.

Comment: @DanielNitzan I think the issue is, you want to know if a new value was added because you have a code branch that occurs if the object didn't exist. That is exactly what computeIfAbsent is though, a code branch if the value doesn't exist.

Comment: @matt yes but the other code path should execute only if the entry already exists; after calling `computeIfAbsent` both code paths would merge, such that the distinction cannot be made without an additional flag.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to store `Future<Value>` instead of `Value` in the map:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Future<Value>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

boolean foo(String key) {
    Future<Value> value = map.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        value = map.putIfAbsent(key, new FutureTask<Value>(() -> new Value()));
        if (value == null) {
            // do some stuff
            return true;
        }
    }
    // do some other stuff
    return false;
}
```

You can access the underlying value by calling `value.get()`, which will block until the computation is complete.

There is a chance that more than one FutureTask is created, but only one will reach the map and only one computation of `new Value()` will be done.

Comment: The problem with this is that you defer the **start** of the creation of `Value` until the point when it is actually needed. If `foo` is called, then the program waits 5 minutes, and then something tries to retrieve that `Value`, the caller has to wait the whole time for `Value` to be created, when it could have either been created synchronously in `foo()` (current behaviour) or during the 5 mins of inactivity. You were onto something with using a Future, but pushing to an executor rather than creating a FutureTask would mitigate some cases of the caller having to wait

Comment: You're right, it doesn't even work with Supplier because it will recalculate everytime. Switching back to FutureTask. And indeed, you can trigger the calculation right after putIfAbsent by calling value.get() or you can send it to an executor.

Answer (score 1):

First let's fix the fact that you are not acting atomically, and do a needless look-up. Two threads could both simultaneously pass the first `value == null` check. Not really a problem now (except 2 `Value`s will be created, which is slow), but a bug waiting to happen if someone adds an else clause to the second `value == null` check. It's cleaner this way too.

```
boolean foo(String key) {
    Value value = map.putIfAbsent(key, new Value());
    if (value == null) {
        // do some stuff
        return true;
    } 
    else {
       // do some other stuff
       return false;
    }
 }
```

Now let's address the fact that `Value` creation is slow (sounds like you are abusing constructor, but anyway).

```
 boolean foo(String key) {
    final AtomicBoolean wasCreated = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    final Value value = map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> {
        wasCreated.set(true);
        return new Value();
    });
    if (wasCreated.get()) {
        // do some stuff
        return true;
    } 
    else {
       // do some other stuff
       return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Or just delete both `return` statements and add `return wasCreated.get();` after the `if else`. You can also delete the `final` keywords - they do nothing useful. And delete `false` too. Less code is good.

Comment: I did the double `null` checks in order to avoid unnecessary object creation in the normal case, i.e. the key already exists. Also, your solution works, but we can do better, perhaps by JDK providing a `putIfAbsent` that gets a lambda for supplying the value.

Comment: @DanielNitzan In general you should be very careful about combining checks and puts for concurrent maps. These compare-and-set operations (`putIfAbsent`, `computeIfAbsent` etc) exist deliberately to make acting atomically easy and efficient. When you wrote this, it should have been a red flag, not just because `Value` creation is slow. Something to keep in mind for the future

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use local state and update it in `computeIfAbsent`'s mapping function:

```
boolean foo(String key) {
    boolean[] b = { false };
    map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> {
        // do some stuff
        b[0] = true;
        return new Value();
    });
    return b[0];
}
```

Because `mappingFunction` is only run if the key is not present in the map, you can guarantee that the heavy `new Value()` is only called when necessary and that the return value is set to `true` only when there was no mapping before the call.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your method `foo` ( which is literally a wrapper for putIfAbsent ).

```
String key = "test";
if(foo(key)){
    //Positive Branch. 
} else{
    //Negative Branch.
}
```

Now, in a multi-threaded environment, thread A calls and completes foo and adds a new value. It is going down the Positive branch. Before it enters the Positive branch, it gets scheduled for later. Thread B calls and completes foo, it continues executing and goes down the Negative branch.

The Negative branch is getting executed before the Positive branch, which in my mind is not wanted. In your particular case it might be OK. `compute` might be a better replacement.

```
map.compute( key, ( k, old ) -> {
    if(old==null){
        Value v = new Value();
        //positive branch.
        return v;
    } else{
        //negative branch.
        return old;
    }
});
```

Now you would be acting atomically on whether or not the value exists.

Comment: The question is only about the context inside `foo`, not about external code calling `foo`. If you want to achieve thread-safe/atomic execution outside of `foo` based on `foo`'s return value, then you need to correctly synchronize your code.

Comment: @DanielNitzan You didn't seem to understand the race condition I was describing which is related to why your expectations of `computeIfAbsent` are a bit of an edge case. If "The question is only about the context inside foo" then compute if absent should be sufficient as it would remove the unecessary value creation and no explicit locks.